# React jwt when token expires user doesn't log out

Tags: reactjs, django, jwt

I am doing an app with django rest framework and react, and I found jwt as a way to set authorization. To do it when the user logins I am setting in localStorage the tokens. My problem is that when token expires user doesn't log out.

frontend

```
let loginUser = async (e )=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                username: e.target.username.value,
                password: e.target.password.value
            })
            setAuthTokens(res.data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(res.data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(res.data))
            navigate('/')
        } catch {
            alert('Something went wrong')
        }
    }
```

django

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(seconds=4),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=90),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You don't check if the token is valid in the frontend? If the token isn't valid you should logout, meaning, delete the token from the localStorage and redirect to the login screen. Also in the backend, you should have some kind of strategy that checks if the user is logged in and check if the token is valid, if not return a 401, if the frontend received a 401 it knows that the user is either not logged in or the token is invalid and should redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actively checking whether the JWT Token is valid or not. That's why it is not logged out automatically.

You can either call an API with an interval to check whether the token is still valid, or on the next API call with Auth JWT token and your backend throws an UNAUTHORIZED status back to notify the frontend so you can write what happens when UNAUTHORIZED is returned by your API call.